# Why bootstrap-based confidence interval didn't include the point estimate?

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, bootstrap

I have constructed a nonparametric bootstrap confidence interval using 1000 iterations. However, I got a result of `CI: 0.72 [0.63, 0.68]`. As you can see, the point estimate is above the upper limit of 95% confidence interval. Now, I have two questions.

1. What are the possible underlying reasons for this?
2. How to interpret and report such results?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What library and methods did you use to compute them?

Comment: As my data is hierarchical, I used `resample_data()` from `fabricatr` package.

Comment: debug your code

Answer (score 2):

There are very many styles of nonparametric bootstrap
confidence intervals. I have used several of them,
and I haven't seen a reasonable method for a 95% bootstrap CI
for a population mean that failed to contain the *sample* mean.
[However, @whuber suggests that a bootstrap CI may not cover the sample mean, if it is based on a small sample from a highly skewed distribution, such as lognormal. Also, @Gada has given a reference about bootstrap CIs that don't contain the *population* mean.]

You have not said
what method you are using or said how large a sample you have.
So, my only direct comment on
your specific interval is to question whether you should
have done at least 2000 iterations. I agree with @Aksakal that
you should check your implementation of the intended style of CI.

Here are two methods applied to a sample of size $n = 25,$
which is contaminated with three observations from a population with
a much larger mean.

```
set.seed(1234)
x = c(rexp(22, 1/5), rexp(3, 1/100))
a = mean(x); a
[1] 10.9786
```

The true population mean (which would be unknown in a real-life
situation) is $\mu = 16.4,$ so I have an 'unlucky' low sample mean.

```
boxplot(x, horizontal = T)
```

[image]

My first bootstrap CI uses a deprecated simple quantile method
known to give bad results for highly skewed samples. With $2000$
iterations it gives the 95% CI $(5.07, 19.26),$ which includes
the sample mean (and the population mean).

```
set.seed(2022)
q = replicate(2000, mean(sample(x,25,rep=T)))
quantile(q, c(.025,.975))
     2.5%     97.5% 
 5.072897 19.260683
```

A simple method, offering some bias protection, gives
the interval $(2.19, 16.88),$ which contains the sample mean
(and, in spite of bad luck, also the population mean).

```
set.seed(124)
d = replicate(2000, mean(sample(x,25,rep=T)) - a)
LU = quantile(d, c(.975,.025))
a - LU
     97.5%      2.5% 
  2.194154 16.876843
```

Comment: Re "I can't see how a reasonable method for a 95% bootstrap CI for a population mean could fail to contain the sample mean:" One common instance where that can occur is bootstrapping a highly skewed distribution, such as a Lognormal.  Bear in mind that the very *first* information the bootstrap gives us is an indication of the bias in an estimator.  A good bootstrap CI incorporates this bias correction--and that's why it might fail to include the sample mean.

Comment: @whuber Tnx. As you said bootstrap CI can fail to include the population mean for skewed data and/or for small to medium sample sizes. For example, one can check the paper written by Hesterberg (2015).

Comment: Re the edit: my argument is unrelated to sample size.  There are Lognormal distributions for which the mean of even a very large sample (by any standard) is likely to be far below the population mean.

Answer (score 2):

Two likely possibilities:

1. Your code is wrong. Double check everything!
2. You have a lot of data, and one ridiculously large outlier that was not sampled in 95% of the 1000 bootstrap repetitions, so didn't affect the 95% CI.

Comment: Actually, my intuition was wrong here - it's actually incredibly unlikely to be case #2!