How do we deal with confidence intervals containing values that are consistent with both the null and alternative hypothesis?
For instance, assume that when testing for a significant difference in means of some measure between a control and a treatment group, I observe a difference in means of 0.5, suggesting the treatment might have had an effect. The 95% confidence interval is (-1, 1).
My interpretation of this result would be that, since the CI contains 0, I can't reject the null hypothesis (no difference in means).
However, so far I've only found examples and explanations where, if the CI contains 0, it does not contain the observed value, or vice versa. I now wonder if a CI containing both 0 and the observed value, as in my example, changes anything about the interpretation, hints at some interesting quality of the data, requires any further testing etc.
(Conversely, what if the CI contains neither of the two values?)

Most CI's will contain the observed value from your sample. (I said most, but I really want to say all? However there could be some pathological counter-examples -which I never encountered in practice-  e.g. where a bootstrapped CI may not include the observed value from the sample?). Definitively all CI's of the means will not only contain the observed mean but will be centered on the observed mean (of the form $\bar x \pm k.s$, where s is the observed standard deviation). So your premise of a CI not containing the observed mean is not possible. Similarly, normal CI of the standard deviation, binomial CI's of a proportion, will always include the observed statistic.
Now this CI may or not include the null hypothesis; in your example, it may or not include 0 (i.e. the difference of means $=0$). If it does not include the null hypothesis, you should reject the null (and the p-value will be below your significance level $\alpha$, assuming your CI is computed at the same significance level). If it does include the null, then logically you can not reject the null (the null value e.g. 0 is a plausible value), and your p-value is this case will always be $>\alpha$).
Your example of a CI containing both the observed mean and 0 is completely normal; it should include the observed value, and the fact that it also includes 0 means you can not reject the null.

This page has an example of your pathological possibility. The pathological bootstrapped CI aren’t really correct, however. (+1)

Thanks for the pathological counter-example! I had a hunch that it may have existed... Hence my reluctance for stating "all CI's"; but it is indeed kind of "the exception which confirms the rule", rather than invalidates it.


I note that the OP's CI cannot be of the form $\hat{\theta}\pm k\cdot s$ for some estimated scale-factor $s$, since it's not centered on the estimate (interval has midpoint at $0$ but the estimate is $0.5$). Fairly ordinary intervals might not include some specific estimates (albeit more easily done if the interval is narrow). For example, an interval with $\alpha/2$ in each tail might not include a mean estimate if the distribution is pretty skewed. (It's even easier with shortest intervals.)


The pathological possibility: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561595/why-bootstrap-based-confidence-interval-didnt-include-the-point-estimate,

Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen for the pathology report.  It is well known that "Statistics means never having to say you are certain". It would seem that a corrolary is "never having to say "impossible".
